# When rendering json in rails, how can I exclude an entry from an included association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have the following line...

```
render json: { user: @user.as_json(except: :password_digest, include: :currency), token: token}
```

However, I would like to `except` an element from the included currency association. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
render json: { user: @user.as_json( except: :password_digest,
  include: { currency: { except: :your_element } } ), token: :token }
```